# parsing string using powershell

Tags: string, parsing, powershell

I am moving aspx files from an old system to the new one using Powershell. I need to parse the page and change href of hyperlink tags as following.

old system
href=/ranet/templates/page____9372.aspx

will be in new system

/newfolder/folder1/9372.aspx

Comment: I used replace method to replace href value. but I need to have a common solution to find all /.../page____number and replace it with /new.../number

Comment: Post your code so we've got a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$input = "href=/ranet/templates/page____9372.aspx"
$new = "/newfolder/folder1/"
$array = $input.Split('_')
$array2 = ($array[$array.Count-1]).Split('.')
$newLine = $new+$array2[0]+".aspx"
$input
$newLine
```

Actually this is not such a great answer as you have to ensure that there are no other underline characters in the page!